# Returning and receiving results of multiple query with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Currently, I am making an ajax call and its returning me data in json format. But what I require is to execute multiple queries and return the results of those queries in separate variables/arrays. How do I execute the queries to return the data in such a way and also how to receive it in the ajax?

Any help is appreciated.

```
$query1 = "SELECT `user`, `age` FROM `users` WHERE `GENDER`= 'M';
$query2 = "SELECT `user`, `age` FROM `users` WHERE `GENDER`= 'F';

$result1 = $connection->query($query1) or die ("error");
$data1 = array();

//loop through the returned data
foreach ($result1 as $row) {
    $data1[] = $row;
 }


//close connection
$connection->close();


 print json_encode($data1);
```

Comment: do the same for query2 and add the resulting data to the object you are going to return (`$data1` in the current case)

Comment: Can you give what your current output looks like and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Also, unless you have more than M/F in gender all you are leaving out is blanks. So you could just do the query with no where and avoid this whole situation?

Comment: I will be using the results to plot bar charts of M/F. So the results must be separate. What I am expecting is something like this

[{"user":"John","age":"35"},{"user":"William","age":"32"}] [{"user":"Amy","age":"28"},{"user":"Rose","age":"30"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you have to assign all array to single array and encode that array

Ex:

```
foreach ($result1 as $row) {
    $data1[] = $row;
 }
$data['array1']=$data1;
foreach ($result2 as $row) {
    $data2[] = $row;
 }
$data['array2']=$data2;
foreach ($result3 as $row) {
    $data3[] = $row;
 }
$data['array3']=$data3;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$data1 = [ ... ]; // array with data
$data2 = [ ... ]; // array with some other data

echo json_encode(array_merge($data1, $data2));
```

Edit:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'data1' => $data1,
    'data2' => $data2
));
```

In javascript you can do `response.data1` and `response.data2`

```
$.ajax({
            url: "testdata.php",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              obj.data1;
              obj.data2;
            } 
});
```

Comment: The above code merges both the arrays. My requirement is to get separate arrays and work with those separately later.

Comment: sorry to bother again. I am new to this. Could you please tell me where to do response.data1 and response.data2. Here is my ajax

$.ajax({
    url: "testdata.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log(obj);
  }

})